# How do I concatenate data in a 2-tuple using Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, java-8

I have data that looks like this:

```
[{"key1" : "a", "key2" : "1"}, {"key1" : "b", "key2" : "2"}, {"key1" : "a", "key2" : "3"}, {"key1" : "c", "key2" : "4"}, {"key1" : "b", "key2" : "5"}, {"key1" : "a", "key2" : "6"}]
```

I want to concatenate it so to look like this:

```
[{"key1" : "a", "key3" : "1, 3, 6"}, {"key1" : "b", "key3" : "2, 5"}, {"key1" : "c", "key3" : "4"}]
```

My class is:

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
class Person {
  String key1;
  String key2;
  String key3;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> byKey1 =
    data
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getKey1));
```

How do I do this using Java 8 Stream API?

Comment: Literally like that, or are you looking for something more like `[{"key1": "a", "key3": ["1", "3", "6"]}, ...]`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I gave the general format of my input and output. The keys, values and their number will be different.

Comment: My point was more general than that. Are you really looking for string concatenation in the values of `key3` or a List of values? The latter is arguably a better way of representing the data and can always be concatenated together after the fact if required as a single string.

Comment: @Blip I couldn't understand the docs on Streams. I have given some sample code I tried.

Comment: @Phylogenesis i am looking for String concatenation as I will have to re-enter the data in another table.

Comment: If you don’t understand the Stream API, just implement you transformation without it. Showing code doing the intended transformation would help understanding your intention as well.

Comment: Most likely, you want to do something like `Map<String, List<String>> result = data .stream() .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getKey1, Collectors.mapping(Person::getKey2, Collectors.toList())));`